# Where did the Buddha say that Teachings that don't contain the Noble Eightfold Path cannot lead to Enlightenment?

Tags: reference-request, pali-canon, the-buddha, enlightenment, eightfold-path

Question is in the title. I remember reading that statement in a Theravada Buddhist book or PDF file but now I can't seem to find it.

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the [Mahaparinibbana Sutta](https://suttacentral.net/dn16/en/sujato). In whichever teaching and discipline/ training the Noble Eightfold Path is not found, the four types of enlightened persons cannot be found also.

> “Subhadda, in whatever teaching and training the noble eightfold path
> is not found, there is no true ascetic found, no second ascetic, no
> third ascetic, and no fourth ascetic. In whatever teaching and
> training the noble eightfold path is found, there is a true ascetic
> found, a second ascetic, a third ascetic, and a fourth ascetic. In
> this teaching and training the noble eightfold path is found. Only
> here is there a true ascetic, here a second ascetic, here a third
> ascetic, and here a fourth ascetic. Other sects are empty of ascetics.
> [DN 16](https://suttacentral.net/dn16/en/sujato)

Comment: Thank you so much for this.